# jmeter-maven-plugin to use logback.xml to load the logs to Elastic bypassing Logstash configs

Tags: maven, jmeter, logback, slf4j, jmeter-maven-plugin

I have an use case where i need to load the Jmeter logs to elastic search without log-stash configurations.

The performance test case is being invoked using pom.xml jmeter-maven-plugin goal.

I wanted below message to be shipped into Elastic,

```
[INFO] summary =    180 in 00:00:01 =  182.6/s Avg:     0 Min:     0 Max:     0 Err:   180 (100.00%)
```

I tried the below mentioned in documentation, instead of log4j2xml i used logback.xml.

([link](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Log-Levels#2))

> Advanced Log Configuration  If you add a "log4j2.xml" into the
>    (defaults to
>   ${project.base.directory}/src/test/conf) it will now be copied into
>   the /bin folder. If one does not exist the default one supplied with
>   JMeter will be used instead.

i also tried to provide the config file as

```
 mvn -X -DAPPCONFIG=home/App1 -Dlogback.configurationFile=file:path/to/conf/logback.xml -Duser.timezone=GMT com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:jmeter -Dtest=TestClass#testmethod
```

In both the cases the logback.xml is not being used. But i noticed that in git the pom.xml includes logback dependencies.

Any input, how to configure the logback.xml instead of log4j2.xml in the jmeter-maven-plugin?

Answer (score 2):

Looking into [Send the Logs of a Java App to the Elastic Stack](https://www.baeldung.com/java-application-logs-to-elastic-stack) it appears that you need to:

1. Add [`logstash-logback-encoder`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.logstash.logback/logstash-logback-encoder) to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) by adding the next line to *pom.xml* file:

   ```
   <testPlanLibraries>
        <artifact>net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:6.2</artifact>
   </testPlanLibraries>
   ```
2. Place a copy of [*log4j2.xml* file](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v5_1_1/bin/log4j2.xml) to `src/test/conf` folder of your Maven project and [configure JMeter logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) according to your requirements. Make sure to add Logstash appender to it like:

   ```
   <appender name="STASH" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
       <file>/desired/location/of/the/log/file</file>
       <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
           <fileNamePattern>/desired/location/of/the/log/file.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
           <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
       </rollingPolicy>
       <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder"/>
   </appender>
   <root level="DEBUG">
       <appender-ref ref="STASH"/>
   </root>
   ```
3. That should be it, you can not point the `logback.xml` to read the configured file(s), convert the output to JSON and feed ELK stack with the data